# Merge two columns and only keep data from second

Tags: r

I am trying to unite two columns but the data Concatenates from each column. I would like to only keep the data from the second column `B` and remove any of the `A` data
column data. Is there a way to do this without 1) Deleting the data manually from the 1st col first? Thank you!

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                  B = c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))

df1 %>% unite("A",A,B,remove = TRUE,na.rm = TRUE)
```

The out returns 1_2 in the combine new column 'A'

Comment: It would help to see sample data, please post the output from `dput(head(test2))`.

Comment: Edited with data example and output - thank you

Comment: Maybe it's best to 
```df1$A <- df1$B |> df1 = select(df1,-`B`)```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you mean. The paragraph mentions columns `Sales Rep` and `REP:`, but your sample data is `A` and `B`; your most recent comment is not legal R code; the title of the question mentions `merge` which is a table-join operation but you suggest `tidyr::unite` which is a string-pasting operation (nothing close to the same). All of this might be cleared up if you clear up the column-name ambiguity and add your expected output given the sample data.

Comment: Sorry - paragraph edit made. I think it's best to 
df1$A <- df1$B |> df1 = select(df1,-`A`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to keep only column B where a value is present, otherwise use column A, like this? So you end up with one column (C) that coalesces A and B?

If you want to delete column A, then just add `%>% select(-A)`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(
  A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
  B = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, 2)
) %>%
  mutate(C = coalesce(B, A))
#>   A  B C
#> 1 1  2 2
#> 2 1  2 2
#> 3 1  2 2
#> 4 1  2 2
#> 5 1  2 2
#> 6 1  2 2
#> 7 1 NA 1
#> 8 1  2 2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I think so - does the coalesce prioritize the first pass 'B' as the priority data. Meaning, what ever data is in A just gets overridden by B data minus NA's? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. First argument takes priority and the second only used where there is missing data in the first.

Comment: Thank you - I like this too because it looks like I can pass multiple columns